# Where can I find Qt4 source code editor widget?

Tags: qt4, editor

I want to provide a QtScript source code editor in my application.
It would be great if this would have source code highlighting and auto completion.

So I don't want to reinvent the wheel: Is there already a quite good widget for that?
I could not find anything on Google...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [QScintilla](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/qscintilla/intro).  It has Javascript highlighting and (auto-)completion support built-in.

Comment: I didn't know that a Qt version of this great component exists!

Comment: Licence restrictions are much more severe than Qt's, unfortunately.

Comment: The QScintilla's License is not so liberal like Qt's now! This is why I downvoted!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtextedit.html) and [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) together to get text editing features with syntax highlighting. See Qt's richtext\syntaxhighlighter example.

QtScript is based on the ECMAScript scripting language as is JavaScript, so I guess you could use JavaScript syntax highlighting without any big problems. So if you don't want to code the new QSyntaxHighlighter from scratch, maybe you could use this [JavaScript editing widget](http://ariya.blogspot.com/2010/09/minimalistic-javascript-editing-widget.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try [stealing the official one](http://svn://labs.trolltech.com/svn/qtscript/qtscriptdebug), you want src/editor/scripthighlighter.h and src/editor/scripthighlighter.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Try KatePart of KDE:

http://kate-editor.org/about-katepart/

To quote:

> KatePart is a fast and feature-rich text editor component with many advanced features. It implements the KTextEditor interfaces, a common interface collection for text editor components in KDE, allowing it to be selected as the editor in applications that lets the user chose from different implementations, and it can use KTextEditor plug-ins.
>
> KatePart is originally based on code from the KDE 1 richtext editor widget, but has been almost completely rewritten over the years. It is the default text editor widget in Kate and KWrite and also the default to display text in Konqueror. A lot of other applications use it as text editing component, too, like KDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

- Full-fledged code editor widget: [QCodeEdit](http://qcodeedit.org/)
- Very simple solution: [QtScript highlighter](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25501-QtScript-script-text-editor-for-Qt-4-4-3-with-Syntax-Highlighter) (MultiLineCommentHighlighter class is defined [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-25483.html))