# Source code edition C++ framework

Tags: c++, frameworks

I would like to include a source code editor inside my software.

The editor should provide at least the following features:

- syntax coloration;
- syntax validation;
- auto-commpletion;
- code folding;
- inline documentation (displays a called function documentation for example);
- extensible, so that it can support more languages in the future;  support at least C++, Python, Java, Doc-book, XML, Latex.

Additionnaly, the framework should be in C++, as my own software that wishes to include the framework is in C++ as well. Ideally, it would use the Qt framework.

Finally, it should work at least for GNU/Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.

I wish to avoid develop it myself, as this seems a long and difficult task, and as I expect this need is quite common and many solutions already exist in the outside world.

So far, I only found QScintilla, but I am surprised there is not much more choice.

Do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734085/qt4-source-code-editor-widget

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [KatePart](http://kate-editor.org/about-katepart) is what you are looking for? It's the editor component used in the Kate editor and the KDevelop IDE included in KDE.

Comment: It might be. I did not know about it. However, I am afraid it will pull out too much KDE dependencies with it. I will investigate it a bit more theroughly though. Thank you for the hint.